# Using the members of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I need to use the GNU-GSL interpolation function, that looks like this:

```
double gsl_interp_eval (const gsl_interp * interp, const double xa[], const double ya[], double x, gsl_interp_accel * acc)
```

But the *xa[]* and *ya[]* arrays that I need are the elements A.x and A.y.value described by these objects:

```
class c_ys {
  double value;
};

struct s_points {
  double x; 
  c_ys  y;
};

class c_curves {
  vector<s_points> A;
};
```

How can I use these elements as second and third arguments in the function gsl_interp_eval?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to do it without making copies, because the offsets in memory between the `double` members is not correct.

Here is how you can do it:

```
double *x = new double[A.size()];
double *y = new double[A.size()];
for (int i = 0 ; i != A.size() ; i++) {
    x[i] = A[i].x;
    y[i] = A[i].y.value;
}
gsl_interp_eval(...); // call your function
delete[] x;
delete[] y;
```